# Grow Flexbox items from the bottom

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I can't believe I am asking this because it must be quite simple. But am working in react-native and have to use flexbox I think for this, but I am open to suggestions.

*** I realize react native would be using Views and not Divs but this question is really about flexbox and I will not be able to use grid for this. Although I am curious how it would be done in grid also

With the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">icon button number one</div>
  <div class="icon">an even larger text with stuff in it
two</div>
  <div class="icon">a large bit of text three</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 3px black solid;
}
.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I am hoping to dynamically be able to grow this 'list' of buttons from the bottom.

As it stands the divs inside the container line up like this

```
<an even larger text with stuff in it two> <icon button number one>
                                        <a large bit of text three>
```

But I want them to line up like this:

```
                                        <a large bit of text three>
<an even larger text with stuff in it two> <icon button number one>
```

How do I get the items to grow from the bottom up when they will eventually be added dynamically?

https://codepen.io/sias/pen/ZEjmXBj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is what you want
wrap reverse just upside down and start and end swapped

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  border: 3px black solid;
  
}
.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Nailed it. :) thank you

Comment: One small edit to make it exactly like the question..  flex-direction: row-reverse in addition to this code. But you found the missing ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 500px;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 3px black dotted;

}
.icon {
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">icon button number one</div>
  <div class="icon">an even larger text with stuff in it
two</div>
  <div class="icon">a large bit of text three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I make these changes I get 3 items stacked on top of each other and in the order they are written: when i switch the flex-flow to column-reverse it does almost accomplish what I want but it isn't wrapping and when i add flex-wrap: wrap or add wrap to the flex-flow property to that, it still isn't wrapping.

Comment: I though you wanted items stacked from the bottom up in a single column? Maybe post a picture of what you are after? Maybe try `flex-flow: column wrap`